# Sequence of positive integers containing every positive integer, find consecutive terms such that sum is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_1,a_2...$ be an infinite sequence containing every positive integer exactly once. Is it always possible to find positive integers $i$, $k$ such that $a_i+a_{i+1} + ... + a_{i+k}$ is a prime?

My thoughts - I'm not completely sure if it is possible or not, but I guess so. However I'm not sure how to find some chunk of sequence with a prime sum; I've tried considering specific numbers, such as primes, composites to no avail.
On the other hand, if it is not possible, then we must construct some sequence such that it is clearly not possible. I am also not sure here; every sequence I've constructed seems to be contradicting the assumption.

Comment: I have doubts, assume that the odd indices contain extremely large numbers , and the even indices fill up the gaps between those. Then, every sum must contain one of those extremely large numbers , hence the sum has very little chance to be prime. This is no disproof, just an intuition leading to the conjecture that we cannot always find such integers.

Comment: Try finding a counterexample, maybe using induction.

Answer (score 2):

Following **Peter**'s suggestion in the comments, it is surely possible to build a sequence without prime sums. Maybe it will get really ugly really fast, but that's another story.

Say we have terms $a_1,\,\dots,\,a_n$ which satisfy the condition (that is, there are no prime sums of consecutive terms among these). Say $r$ is the smallest number that is still not in the sequence. Now let's find the smallest $k$ such that none of the numbers $k+a_n,\,k+a_n+a_{n-1},\,\dots,\,r+k,\,r+k+a_n,\,\dots$ is prime. In other words, $k$ must avoid the union of $2n$ shifted copies of the prime series. This is guaranteed to be possible, because the [asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Properties_and_examples) of prime numbers is $0$, and we only have finitely many copies of them. Now let $a_{n+1}=k,\,a_{n+2}=r$. Continue *ad infinitum*.

So it goes.

Comment: You did not consider that the sequence must contain every positive integer exactly once. Otherwise we could just begin the sequence with the even numbers larger than $2$ (obviously no sum of such numbers can be prime) and let then follow the odd numbers and $2$ , which is of course impossible since there cannot be anything after infinite many entries.

Comment: Yes I did consider that. On each step, I add two terms. One of them is big and ugly. Another is the smallest integer which is not in the sequence so far. What will I miss?

Comment: So you consider the smallest not yet appearing number in your construction , right ? OK, that makes sense. Nice answer (+1)